# Ordinal Regression: Significant p-values and no colinearity, but very high misclassification error

Tags: modeling, ordinal-data, predictor, ordered-logit

I cannot show the **R** code, since it is about a confidential research project. I hope someone can still help me make sense of this.

I conducted ordinal logistic regression with a few ordinal, discrete, and binary predictor variables and an ordinal response variable. I checked for collinearity and removed any variables with high **pvalues** from the formula.
When I then use the model for prediction and check its misclassification error, I get values between **40-50%**.

How can that be? What contributes to this high value?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you see as the problem? // Checking for high p-values, removing those features, and fitting the regression on the remaining features is problematic, though addressing that is somewhat different from what seems to be your main point of confusion.

Comment: Removing variables based on p-values is not usually a good idea, and may well harm the prediction quality.

Comment: The other thing is that ordinal regression is not classification. I don't know how many categories your response variable has, but ordinal regression doesn't only care about classification but also about getting close in case of not getting it totally right. With many categories 40-50% isn't that bad, and if you really wanted to optimise misclassification, methods for categorical classification should be better than ordinal regression (which cares about another aim).

Comment: Even another thing is that some classification/regression problems just don't allow for high precision prediction. Even if your x-variables have something to do with the y, the relation may be weak, and predicting the y correctly may be very hard.

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far. Why is removing variables based on p-values not a good idea? I thought that the t/p-values that the polr function gives, are an indicator of whether the predictor variable is signficantly correlated with the outcome variable, holding all other variables constant?
Is there a way to get a more nuanced classification table that takes into account how close the prediction got? The outcome variable has 5 levels, and the model didnt predict anything for levels 3 to 5

Comment: "Why is removing variables based on p-values not a good idea?" If you don't remove a variable, the coefficient estimator is the best guess for its impact. If you remove it, its coefficient is automatically set to zero, which is worse, more often than not (although not always). Furthermore, if you remove more than one variable at a time, you may lose information that is shared between them but may not make any single one significant as long as the other(s) are still there.

Comment: "Is there a way to get a more nuanced classification table that takes into account how close the prediction got?" You can see that looking at the full classification table.

Comment: Removing "insignificant" variables represents bad statistical practice and ruins standard errors even more than it ruins coefficient estimates.  This site is filled with topics on this subject.  I suggest your read some of them.  Also google "Stepwise FAQ".